# How can I write to getpass() input from a parent process?

Tags: c, linux, input, passwords, popen

Suppose I have the following short program, which I will call `Parent.c`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char buffer[100];
    memset(buffer, '\0', 100);
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    FILE* child =  popen("./child","w");
    fwrite(buffer, 1, strlen(buffer), child);
    pclose(child);

}
```

Now there are two cases for `child.c`.

Case 1:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char buffer[100];
    memset(buffer, '\0', 100);
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}
```

Case 2:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char* password = getpass("");
    printf("%s\n", password);

}
```

In case one, if I run `./Parent`, and then type "Hello World", I get two echos of "Hello World". One is from the child program and one is from the parent program.

In case two, if I run `./Parent`, and then type "Hello World", I get one echo of "Hello World", and then get an input prompt from the child process.
If I then type "Goodbye" at this prompt, I will get an echo of "Goodbye".

How can I modify `Parent.c` to get the same behavior in Case 2 that currently occurs in Case 1?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: You can't.

From the [`getpass` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpass):

> The **getpass()** function opens `/dev/tty` (the controlling terminal of the process), outputs the string prompt, turns off echoing, reads one line (the "password"), restores the terminal state and closes `/dev/tty` again.

That means it reads from the terminal device directly, and not from standard input.

Comment: If it reads from /dev/tty, is there some hack to make the parent write to tty just before it reads, or having the parent trick the child into behaving as though /dev/tty is actually a pipe that the parent controls?

Comment: @merlin2011 Not really, `/dev/tty` is the terminal for the _current_ process only. You can't know, from beforehand, which pseudo-terminal it really will be. You might have to rethink what you have in mind, especially since (also from the `getpass` manual page): "This function is obsolete. Do not use it."

Comment: what are the modern equivalents of it?